# Simple Manipulate produces front-end freeze

Tags: manipulate, front-end, windows

I am using Mathematia 12.1 on Windows. I experience a front-end freeze when I evaluate a certain `Manipulate` expression. I have reduced the code down to a rather simple case.

I found that when I evaluate

```
Manipulate[
  Table[u = a, {a, {1, 2, 3}}], 
  {i, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

there is no problem. The output is

[image]

However, when I evaluate

```
Manipulate[
 Table[u = a; u, {a, {1, 2, 3}}], 
 {i, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

the output is

[image]

Notice that the output cell seems always running, and my front-en freezes. I have to kill it in task manager.

What is wrong?

Comment: add the option `TrackedSymbols :> {i}`?

Comment: @kglr Hi, kglr. I tried `TrackedSymbols :> {i}`, it remove the stuck. But I don't understand what is going on. Why we must need `TrackedSymbols :> {i}`?

Comment: matheorem, you might find the section _Controlling Automatic Reevaluation_ in the tutorial [AdvancedManipulateFunctionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html) useful.

Comment: @kglr Thank you so much! Exactly what I am missing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you give that produces constant re-evaluation by the front-end can be further reduced to

[image: busy]

But on my system (I'n running V12.1 on MacOS 10.13.4), there is no freeze. The cell bracket is only saying the cell is busy. Other evaluations can be made while the `Manipulate` output cell is in the busy state. The evaluation can be stopped by simply deleting the output cell.

The same is true for the code in you post. In fact, I can get both my reduced version and your posted version to run at the same time and still do other computations.

The problem, if it is to be considered a problem, arises because `Manipulate` expressions are rewritten when they are evaluated and all free variables in the expression become local variables of a `DynamicModule` that gets wrapped around the `Manipulate` code. By default, such variables are automatically tracked by the front-end while the `Manipulate` is running. Hence, the busyness.

In a comment to your questions, kglr describes the standard practice for reducing the busyness.

```
Manipulate[
  Table[u = a; u, {a, {1, 2, 3}}],
  {i, None},
  TrackedSymbols :> {}]
```

Here are two more:

```
Manipulate[
  Table[Block[{u}, u = a; u], {a, {1, 2, 3}}],
  {i, None}]

Manipulate[
  Once @ Table[u = a; u, {a, {1, 2, 3}}],
  {i, None}]
```

The 1st works by localizing `u` in the `Table` expression, so it doesn't get put into the list of dynamic variables of the `DynamicModule` wrapper. The 2nd works by telling Mathematica to evaluate the table just once and remember the result.

Comment: Thank you so much, m_goldberg. You are right. I also have noticed that Linux version Mathematica doesn't get frozen when such Manipulate evaluates. But windows version does get frozen(at least mine). That's too bad for windows. I always feel my windows Mathematica has a slow front end. Why haven't the developers found this issue? Maybe they mostly develope Mathematica on Linux :)

Comment: @matheorem. As s MacOS user, I naturally think it is a better OS than Windows, but I still think Windows gets a great deal of attention from the Mathematica developers because it is important market for Wolfram Research. Probably more important than Linux. Maybe more important than MacOS. Also, since MacOS is based on BSD Unix, it behaves more like Linux than Windows.